# window.onunload doesn't complete when closing IE

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a web app running in ie, and when i close the application with click "X" right corner on IE, it will call(by javascript window.onunload) a struts action and delete a record in a table in database. 
But now I found it was incorrect sometimes. the record was not deleted sometimes when i close ie. It should be the case that struts action was not be called when record was not deleted.

More interesting is that when I open Fiddler, record was deleted correctly when close ie everytime, no fail case.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: bad practice to do a server action in onunload, dont use in production

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on "onunload" event.

Think about it from the perspective of a web-browser: Should it wait till all open pages process "onunload" event, even if it takes 30 seconds? Probably browser reliably fires the "onunload" event to all open tabs, however it waits just very short time to complete them. Thats why you see inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have to use onunload event, because the page need to show a confirm message to user apart from deleting record, I have used 'onbeforeunload' event for it, then I have to use onunload event for deleting record. Could you please give some more suggestion?

Comment: Yes, another suggestion, as a user: The pages which display confirmation message when I close them - absolutely suck (excuse me my language). Never ever do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to do this, take a look at [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload), but its implementation is inconsistent across browsers: IIRC, opera doesn't implement it.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have used onbeforeunload event for give user alert message. I can not capture user click 'OK' or 'cancel' on alert message. So i have to use onunload event for record deleting. by the way. My app is only for IE. so no need to consider other web browsers. Could you please give me more suggestion?